# why does this php script always show "kiriman gagal diterima" (failed to receive)?

Tags: php, curl

I have two server, it works on the old server but it don't work if I changed the target site to my new server. It shows "failed to receive" (kiriman gagal diterima). My pc executed this php script to send some data from my pc to the destination server

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B54KbvdD3EiLGWUI6vqs9g4oGfU56cc_

php 5.6.38 on new server, php 5.6.34 on old server

This is the error.log

```
[Tue Nov 20 05:32:16.691683 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2916:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 20 05:32:16.785283 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 2916:tid 276] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Nov 20 05:32:16.816483 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2916:tid 276] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

This is access log from xampp

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2018:15:54:46 +0800] "POST /present/present/transmit/sync/json HTTP/1.1" 200 39 "http://127.0.0.1/present/present/client/sinkron" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2018:16:12:06 +0800] "POST /present/present/transmit/sync/json HTTP/1.1" 200 39 "http://127.0.0.1/present/present/client/sinkron" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2018:18:04:51 +0800] "POST /present/present/transmit/sync/json HTTP/1.1" 200 39 "http://127.0.0.1/present/present/client/sinkron" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Nov/2018:18:05:50 +0800] "POST /present/present/transmit/sync/json HTTP/1.1" 200 39 "http://127.0.0.1/present/present/client/sinkron" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

a co worker said the curl isn't running on the new server but last time I checked it, curl is already enabled.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 bionic on new server, old server is using ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Comment: Hi there, I think you need to share a bit more information, copy & paste the PHP error or Notice. Knowing the PHP version also helps. Also share the steps you've already taken to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: old server : php 5.6.34
new server : php 5.6.38

Comment: I might be seeng it wrong, but I only see  a very big class definition in the code example. Could you perhaps add the actual usage of this class? Adding to all the functions defined there

Comment: You are getting this notice, because the httpd does not like your SSL certificate. It's looks like that something is wrong whith your Apache configs,specifically with your SSL setups. The is some more info on the problem [Here](https://community.bitnami.com/t/apache-error-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-which-matches-the-server-name/52679)

Comment: There is something is wrong with my new server but I can't find the problem. Do you have more guess other than ssl certificate problem?

Comment: @user3122286 Considering that you are using xammp and considering the three messages from error log, that you provided, I am afraid no. The three messages are directly related to SSL setups. Also judging by the lines from `access.log`, your post data is sent, so curl must have worked. My guess is that there is an error in php logic somewhere, there is too much commented code. My advice is to remove it, if you don't need it. Also check the post data, check the places where the functions for sending data are called. The source of the problem with logic is likely somewhere there.

Comment: @user3122286 Also the code you provided is a definition of `class` with some functions. But where are the functions used? there must be some more code, because the code provided, doen't output `kiriman gagal diterima` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. My co worker successfully solved the problem